# laravel Inertia vue form event triggered even on non-submit button

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a form in my Vue.js app with a submit button that triggers a loading spinner when clicked. Heres my code:

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

defineProps({ errors: Object })

const form = reactive({
  email: null,
  password: null, 
  remember: null,
  loading: false
})
 
function submit() {  
    router.post('/login', form) 
}
router.on('start', () => {
  form.loading = true
})

router.on('finish', () => {
  form.loading = false
})


</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit" action="post">
   <h5>Login </h5>
   <input v-model="form.email" type="text" ><label>Email</label>  
   <input v-model="form.password" type="password" ><label>Password</label>
   <button :class="form.loading ? 'spinner' : ''" type="submit" >{{form.loading ? "Processing..." : 'Login' }}</button>
   </form> 
<Link href="/register"> Register </Link>
<Link href="/home" ><i>home</i></Link>
```

For example when I click on the "register" link, the loading spinner appears even though the submit button was not clicked and that register link is also outside of the form scope. Can anyone help? I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `<Link>` is part of the routing component, so clicking on that link should trigger the start event of the router, right? Thats how I see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `useForm` instead

```
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const form = useForm({
    email: null,
    password: null, 
    remember: null,
    loading: false
});

const submit = () => {
    form.loading = true
    form.transform(data => ({
        ...data,
        remember: form.remember ? 'on' : '',
    })).post(route('login'), {
        onFinish: () => { 
            form.loading = false
            form.reset('password')
        },
    });
};
```

`route('login')` put the route name here instead of the link